# Calculating entropy for mnist classificiation using Tensorflow and Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, mnist, entropy

What I try to do, is calculating the entropy of my classification accuracies.
I have trained a model and let it do **predictions** on the test data **10 times** (these vary since I change the model a little each time). The test data is **1000 images** from mnist and since mnist has **10** **classes** I end up with an array with the following dimensions:
**(10, 1000, 10)**

What I did next is calculating the mean for the first dimension so I get the average of all my predictions: **(1000, 10)**

What Iam interested now is the entropy of each class, so I calculated :

```
np.sum((-1) * data * log(data), 0)
```

I got the source here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02910.pdf

The problem is that my entropy value is not between 0 and 1 and I end up with values around 50 or more.
I saw that a lot of people used to count their data before and divide it with the result to get the occurrences of each value.
This confuses me since I have values like 0,01445 which tends to not repeat itself. I have my ten classes already given by the position of the value inside the array (10 mnist classes last dimension).

I just want to see the entropy for every class.

I hope you can help

Comment: You can compute CategoricalCrossentropy using `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` when there are more than two label classes. For more details about the library please find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy).Thanks!